# Android: starting device-specific Cyanogenmod/AOSP image on an emulator (qemu)

Tags: android, device, android-source, qemu

My current project involves shipping of a custom firmware, based on Cyanogenmod and targeted to Nexus series of devices, and I want to save some time on build testing - by using virtual devices instead of real devices. (As a part of project's definition - there's a lot of native code for ARM platform, so I can't build "aosp_x86_64-eng" targe)

Of course, there are all sorts of goldfish/m_e_arm-userdebug/generic/ranchu targets available, but I want to test actual device-specific build.

From my observations with MTK-device firmwares, at least boot partition image always included some of ranchu/goldfish-related files, so I suspect the resulting image should be runnable on qemu-system-arm. (no modem, probable no keyboard/touchscreen, but still possible to see whenever kernel and userland apps start?)

`~/Android/Sdk/tools/emulator -avd test-cm -verbose -show-kernel -shell -kernel ./kernel-qemu -gpu on -ramdisk ./deb/ramdisk -system ./deb/system.img` crashes - not able to mount ramdisk.

Using `-kernel ./deb/kernel` causes another crash - emulator can't find Linux version string in a (compressed?) kernel image.

I see that there was a [way to boot CM on qemu with u-boot](https://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=2433499), also there's a real [long command for starting Ranchu build of Android L, using VNC for desktop access](https://www.cnx-software.com/2014/08/23/how-to-build-and-run-android-l-64-bit-arm-in-qemu/), but there's no information on starting device-specific builds.

The question is, does AOSP/CM's release/QA pipeline involves running full device builds on QEMU, and if it does - how to reproduce it? Documentation is real scarce on that.